# How to check between a value python

Tags: python, html, api, integer

```
ItemList = []
for t in FindT:
    int_t = int(t.string.replace("\n",""))
    ItemList.append(int_t)
    List = ItemList

print(ItemList)
List = statistics.mode(ItemList)
print(List)
```

When i run the above code it puts values into a list like this

```
[750, 750, 750, 800, 750, 700, 700, 750, 700, 700, 750, 750, 800, 850, 650, 750, 750, 800, 800, 800, 550, 750, 850, 750, 5000, 750, 500, 750, 750, 500, 750, 700, 650, 700, 700, 750, 600, 500, 700, 700, 700, 900, 2500, 2500, 1300, 1100, 300, 600, 300, 700, 550, 350, 1350]
750
```

I want to find all the values which fall within like 300 above or below the 750 and i have tried, If you can help I would be greatful

```
is_between = -300 <= List <= +300
print(is_between)
```

The ItemList has the raw int list with all the numbers and the List is when i get the mode from the ItemList

Comment: By the way, in your example code: `is_between = -300 <= List <= +300`, do you mean ItemList instead of List? Just a remark.

Comment: So the list value is 750 and i want to find all values which are 300/-300 from the ItemList

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the list element from the mode, and use `abs()` to convert that to a positive number. Then use a list comprehension to get all the matching elements.

```
is_between = [item for item in ItemList if abs(item - List) <= 300]
```

Comment: Hey i tried that and got an error saying "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: Sorry, got confused about which variable has the list.

Comment: Its the ItemList

Comment: I thought that was the output of `print(List)`. I updated the answer to use `ItemList`. Why would you call something `List` if it's not a list?

Comment: Idk when i was just trying to figure something it was the first thing i taught of so ye probably should've used something else